# lubridate ceiling_date bug with daylight savings

Tags: r, lubridate

I use the R package `lubridate` to manipulate date-times that are affected by daylight savings. For example, my timezone is `Australia/Adelaide`, and in 2017, clocks were wound back one hour at Sunday 2 April 2017 0300, and wound forward one hour at Sunday 1 October 2017 0200.

However, the function `lubridate::ceiling_date` behaves strangely with respect to daylight savings.

Suppose we have the following vectors:

```
dt_1 <- lubridate::ymd("2017-10-01", tz = "Australia/Adelaide") %>%
    magrittr::add(lubridate::hours(c(0,1,23,24)))

dt_2 <- lubridate::ymd("2017-04-02", tz = "Australia/Adelaide") %>%
    magrittr::add(lubridate::hours(c(0,1,23,24)))
```

Then `lubridate::floor_date` works as expected.

```
lubridate::floor_date(dt_1, unit = "days")
[1] "2017-10-01 ACST" "2017-10-01 ACST" "2017-10-01 ACST" "2017-10-02 ACDT"

lubridate::floor_date(dt_2, unit = "days")
[1] "2017-04-02 ACDT" "2017-04-02 ACDT" "2017-04-02 ACDT" "2017-04-03 ACST"
```

However, `lubridate::ceiling_date` yields dates that aren't midnight.

```
lubridate::ceiling_date(dt_1, unit = "days")
[1] "2017-10-01 00:00:00 ACST" "2017-10-02 01:00:00 ACDT" "2017-10-02 01:00:00 ACDT" "2017-10-02 00:00:00 ACDT"

lubridate::ceiling_date(dt_2, unit = "days")
[1] "2017-04-02 00:00:00 ACDT" "2017-04-02 23:00:00 ACST" "2017-04-02 23:00:00 ACST" "2017-04-03 00:00:00 ACST"
```

- From the first element of each output vector, `ceiling_date` on the midnight on the changeover date are correct (the first element of each vector).
- From the fourth element of each output vector, `ceiling_date` on the midnight after the changeover date are correct (the fourth element of each vector).
- However, from the second and third elements of each vector, `ceiling_date` on date-times on the changeover date after midnight yield a date-time that is one hour before or after midnight. This is true for times both before and after the changeover time.

If this isn't a bug, then it's certainly unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue (reported separately by another user at https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/605) is now resolved as of lubridate 1.7.3.